# How do you make a favicon appear on a redirected site?

Tags: html, favicon, redirects

I have a Wordpress blog hosted on my domain.  I have redirected a URL to a subfolder of my domain where the blog is installed.  How can I get a specific favicon to appear for that blog but NOT for my primary website?  The favicon appears if I use:

www.kleymeyer.com/laketravisparents

but not if navigating using the redirected site:

www.laketravisparents.com

And very annoyingly, only with the Chrome browser, the Time Warner RoadRunner icon will appear as a favicon when using www.laketravisparents.com !

Comment: You should take that up with RoadRunner. A lot of ISPs are doing skeezy things like that these days. E.g. acting like typosquatters by hijacking DNS errors and sending you to their sponsored search page.

Answer (score 4):

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/myicon.ico">
```

- [Favicon entry @ Wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)